# How to calculate $\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How would I go about calculating $$\int_{\gamma} \left(\frac{z}{z-w}\right)^{n}~dz$$ for $n\leq0$ where $\gamma$ is simple and closed and $w$ lies inside $\gamma$?

My initial thought was to try and use Cauchy Integral Formula I don't know how to deal with the $n$ exponent.

For $n\leq0$ $$\int_{\gamma} \left(\frac{z}{z-w}\right)^{n}~dz=\int_{\gamma} \left(\frac{z-w}{z}\right)^{-n}~dz$$ so the numerator is holomorphic on the entirety of $\mathbb{C}$ but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's integral formula for derivatives?

Comment: Yes I do, but that involves the $n$th derivative of the function I don't know how to interpret this for $n<0$

Comment: Not on the right-hand side.  On the right-hand side, you just have $f(x)$.

Comment: We have $\int_{\gamma} \left(\frac{z}{z-w}\right)^{n}~dz=\frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)! } f^{(n-1)}(w)$ right? How does that help me?

Comment: You have $f^{(n)}(w) = \frac{n!}{2\pi \mathrm{i}} \oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z-w)^{n+1}} \,\mathrm{d}z$.  So, you want $f(z) = z^{[\text{something}]}$ to make the integral match, which forces the rest of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $\;-m=n<0\implies m>0\;$, so

$$\oint_\gamma\left(\frac z{z-w}\right)^ndz=\oint_\gamma\frac{(z-w)^m}{z^m}dz=\begin{cases}0\;,&\gamma\;\text{doesn't enclose zero}\\{}\\\left.\frac{2\pi i}{(m-1)!}\frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}}\left((z-w)^m\right)\right|_{z=0}\;,&\gamma\;\text{encloses zero}\end{cases}$$